# I completely messed up my entire file system permissions. I recovered, but how can I make sure my system is correct throughout?

Tags: permissions, data-recovery

I just `chmod 755` all directories, `644` to all files, and made sure directories such as `/usr/bin/` all have +x bit, but I am not the most knowledgeable about the file system structure, how do I make sure everything is correct? (I accidentally `chmod 644 /` my entire system before this and that's how I messed it up initially)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sure method is to re-install. If you make a backup you could do a re-install without formatting /. That would overwrite all system files with their correct permissions.

> I just chmod 755 all directories, 644 to all files

That is not correct for all the files on your system. It might make your system use able though.

Examples:

- /tmp/ needs 777 and sticky bit set.
- Logfiles in /var/log/, some should be 640 (like `syslog`) to prevent "others" looking at your log files.

Comment: Oh, yeah I definitely looked into some of the stuff you mentioned, I just didn't know if there's anything that I missed - like I have my system up and files accessible but wanted to know if there's stuff like in your answer I need to make sure I change.  Is there anything else you can think of? Thanks for the help

Comment: Just make sure you can make a backup of your personal files and know you can restore it. If you have that set nothing to worry about when you format the machine.

Comment: That actually might be a better use of my time