# How do I save a list of packages which are installed from `initramfs`?

Tags: filesystem, initramfs, recovery-mode

Currently working on getting full shell access, but I messed up root permissions recovering from a rootkit and instead am just migrating home and configs to a fresh install. I have full file system access but none of the commands like `apt`

I would like to know - where can I find a list of all of the packages/dependencies which I have installed with my current OS?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of booting to intramfs using `rdinit=/bin/sh` use `init=/bin/bash` to get a bash shell.

Now your `root` file system is ready to investigate , run:

```
grep -i package: /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

it will show you all installed package in your broken system like:

```
...
Package: libunity-protocol-private0
Package: libvamp-hostsdk3v5
Package: libzltext-data
Package: linux-headers-generic
Package: libzlui-qt4
...
```

you can also get list of only names like this:

```
grep -i package: /var/lib/dpkg/status | awk -F ': ' '{ print $2 }'
```

we can even change the `awk` to `'{ print $2, "install" }'` so we can use the output with `dpkg --set-selections` to install them in new system.

Comment: I can't get into /bin/bash because my file system permissions are messed up. I'm trying to figure out the intramfs to manually get in by setting the file permissions - currently I can switch root and init my standard init thing(don't really know what that means but yeah) and it sets up the standard root FS but init denies access because I still have files that are messed up somewhere (permissions).

Comment: Or is there an easier way to get bash shell? where do I put the argument `init=/bin/bash`? grub config? Cause other than that I do: mount sda1 -> /root/, mount /dev/ -> root/dev/, and try to manually init. Am I missing something for the init process? (Here's some context: https://askubuntu.com/q/915672/626045)

Comment: Have you tried rescue option in GRUB menu?

Comment: No, just recovery mode, if that's not the same thing? I boot to grub and remove the UUID for root in the grub config to recovery because I can't boot normally. EDIT: what should my permissions for /scripts/. be?

Comment: They are the same, if you can boot into recovery mode, then the commands in my answer will work for you. I read your other question today, the only thing you can do to fix the issue is a fresh install. you can also boot your system using a live Ubuntu disk, then mount your root partition and use the commands in the answer to get a list of installed softwares on your machine.

Comment: Gotcha, so I am able to access all apt, aptitude, and dpkg command line tools just from here (still am getting denied bash) anyways so it looks like I'm all set, thanks for the help!